# Create an STL std::set in C# and marshal to c++

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

What would be the best way to achieve this?  I've got a list of filenames, generated in a C# windows service.  I need to ultimately get them into an STL set, and push that to a filemapping.  I assume actually creating this structure in C# is either prohibited, or just too difficult to be worthwhile, but could I use a native dll that returns a pointer to the set it created, that I then pass along in the filemapping?  Any thoughts here would be helpful!

Comment: A `std::set` is likely to contain pointers which would be totally invalid in any context other than the program that created it. I don't think writing it to a file mapping would be possible, even if you had some miracle library that could simulate it in C#. I think you accepted an answer on your previous question prematurely.

Comment: Yeah, my reading is leading me to the same conclusion.  I still think the answer to the last post is acceptable, as it answers my direct question, and would be applicable in non-interop scenarios, but that could very well be misleading.

Comment: "I need to ultimately get them into an STL set, and push that to a filemapping"

are you absolutely sure that is what you need? filemapping (or, as I understand, memory mapped file) does not reflect the state of your heap, but objects in std::set will be on the heap, not in the (shared) address space of the memory mapped file. 

I suppose there is some more-or-less proprietary API you should use instead to either build relevant structure, or pass it to the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a `std::set` in C# is not really practical.  However it is possible to communicate the collection of names into C via PInvoke and put them into an `std::set` there.

```
extern "C" {

  void PassNames(const wchar** ppNames, int nameCount) {
    std:set<std::string> nameSet;
    for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++) {
      nameSet.insert(ppNames[i]);
    }

    PassOfTheSet(nameSet);
  }
}
```

Then you could call this function from C# using PInvoke and hence pass of the data to native

```
[DllImport("TheDllName.dll")
public static extern void PassNames(string[] names, int nameCount);
```

Comment: Ultimately I needed to go in a different direction because of some specific needs, but this is a great answer.